# How to generate XML using SQL PATH Mode, with Line Items

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to generate an XML string based on data in two SQL tables. One contains Order Header data, the other one Line Item data.

My problem is that I can't get the Line Item info to appear properly as multiple elements within a single order:

This is the SQL statement:

```
Select  
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(H.CustPONbr)) As "Transactions/Transaction/CustomerOrdNumber",              
                    (
                    Select LTRIM(RTRIM(InvtID)) As "data()" From X888_Amazon_Order_Line L1 
                    Where L1.CpnyID = H.CpnyID And L1.CustPONbr = H.CustPONbr
                    FOR XML PATH (''), ELEMENTS
                    ) As "Transactions/Transaction/LineItems/LineItem/InvtId"

                From X888_Amazon_Order_Header H (nolock)
                 where h.CustPONbr = '99999014'
                For XML PATH ('ProcessEngineSubmission'), Root ('XML'), ELEMENTS
```

This is the result that I get:

```
<XML>
    <Transactions>
      <Transaction>
        <CustomerOrdNumber>99999014</CustomerOrdNumber>
        <LineItems>
          <LineItem>
            <InvtId>TEST 1235 TEST 1234</InvtId>
          </LineItem>
        </LineItems>
      </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
</XML>
```

If I execute the inner select (replacing "data()" with InvtId), I get what I am trying to achieve:

```
<InvtId>TEST 1235</InvtId>
<InvtId>TEST 1234</InvtId>
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag dbms used. Some product specific SQL there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

Nested selects need the `,TYPE` extension to come back as XML...

You might need to specify a path in the inner `PATH('')` or give a name to the column with `AS` ...

```
Select LTRIM(RTRIM(H.CustPONbr)) As "Transactions/Transaction/CustomerOrdNumber"
      ,(
            Select LTRIM(RTRIM(InvtID))  
            From X888_Amazon_Order_Line L1 
            Where L1.CpnyID = H.CpnyID And L1.CustPONbr = H.CustPONbr
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ) As "Transactions/Transaction/LineItems/LineItem/InvtId"

From X888_Amazon_Order_Header H (nolock)
where h.CustPONbr = '99999014'
For XML PATH ('ProcessEngineSubmission'), Root ('XML')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding the 'TYPE' extension did it.